# Is it possible to filter the results of an included entity in the following LINQ statement

Tags: linq, filter

I would like to filter the `Users` entity in this LINQ statement by a boolean property it contains. Is that possible?

```
var Subscriber = db.Subscribers
                           .Include(s => s.Users)
                           .Include(s => s.SubscriberNotes)
                           .Include(s => s.Orders)
                           .Include(s => s.Websites.Select(w => w.DomainNames))
                           .Single(s => s.SubscriberId == id);
```

Something like `Where S.Users.isOwner = true`

Comment: What does this have to do with MVC?

Comment: Edited and removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the original dataset available, I'll give you some code from the top of my head - I guess you could do something like this:

```
db.Subscribers.Include(s => s.Users.Where(user => user.IsOwner == true))
```

... and then continue with the remaining `Include` statements.